# Capturing particular part of Integer Value from part of a String value

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, vertica

I have a table like `cust_attbr` consists column `attbr` which has values like:

```
{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300",เอ็ก10110","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":"0835546003122"}

{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300", กรุงค10110","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":"0835546003122"}

........ ...  ...
{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300", กรุงค10110","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":" "}
```

So, I have to write one select statement which will fetch only VAT_NUMBER value like:

```
0835546003122
0835546003122
.... ... ..
null
```

Comment: does every row have a json element ? The double quotes around the curly braces - are those in the table too ? What version are you on ?

Comment: yes every rows have value like this only.

Answer (score 1):

With sample data you posted:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID ATTBR
---------- ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         1 "{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300",????10110","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":"0835546003122"}"
         2 "{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300", ?????10110","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":"0835546003122"}"
         3 "{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300", ?????10110","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":" "}"
```

this might be one option:

```
SQL> select id,
  2    regexp_substr(regexp_substr(attbr, 'VAT_NUMBER":"(\d+)?'), '\d+$') vat
  3  from test;

        ID VAT
---------- --------------------
         1 0835546003122
         2 0835546003122
         3

SQL>
```

Inner `regexp_substr` returns `VAT_NUMBER` followed by optional number, while the outer one extracts only the number anchored to the end of the previous substring.

Answer (score 0):

One option would be converting those column values to JSON syntax an then extract the values of `VAT_NUMBER` keys provided DB version is `12c Release 1+`. Here, we have an issue that there are unrecognized characters, probably an alphabet from far east and those strings are not properly quoted, then we need to remove the part upto `TAXAMT` key, and then extracting `VAT_NUMBER` key's value through prefixing an opening curly brace(`'{'`) by use of `JSON_VALUE()` function :

```
SELECT JSON_VALUE(
                  '{'||REGEXP_REPLACE(str,'(.*10110",)(.*)','\2'),
                  '$.VAT_NUMBER'
                  ) AS VAT_NUMBER        
  FROM tab  --> your original data source
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=7ad30398955f1641ae03b5a4d7c51b36)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

If you're on 18c and the data is actual json (it currently is not because of the double quotes around the curly braces and the ",.กรุงค10110" - It is unclear that this is because of your sample data) you could use json_table function:

```
WITH t (json_val) AS
(
  SELECT '{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":"0835546003122"}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":"0835546003122"}' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT '{"SRCTAXAMT":"11300","TAXAMT":"11300","LOGID":"190301863","VAT_NUMBER":" "}' FROM DUAL
)
SELECT jt.*
FROM   t,
       JSON_TABLE(json_val, '$'
         COLUMNS (first_name    VARCHAR2(50 CHAR) PATH '$."VAT_NUMBER"')) jt;

0835546003122
0835546003122
```